# Failed to get properties: No such interface ''

Tags: debian-wheezy, systemctl

i try to start my new service :

**/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=My Desc...
After=network.target

[Service]
User=webXX
Group=clientXX
ExecStart=/var/www/xxx/xxx/xxx/golang-binay /var/www/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I did `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl enable myservice` then
`systemctl start myservice` but after trying to start i have an error:

```
Failed to start myservice.service: Unknown unit: myservice.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status myservice.service' for details.
```

and if i get status, i have this message `Failed to get properties: No such interface ''`